# Symfony2 is not using the config_prod.yml

Tags: php, .htaccess, symfony, config

I have a symfony2 -project, but I cannot get it to use my config_prod.yml.
I've set 2 database hosts in the parameters.yml. Other for devving in localhost and other for production. I call these parameters in the config_dev.yml and config_prod.yml accordingly, but the one in the prod is not working. It always uses the database in the config_dev.yml, and if I put the prod -database url into the config_dev.yml, it connects there. It doesn't matter what I put into the config_prod.yml, it never uses those values.

Here's my config_dev.yml:

```
imports:
    - { resource: config.yml }

framework:
    router:
        resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing_dev.yml"
        strict_requirements: true
    profiler: { only_exceptions: false }

web_profiler:
    toolbar: true
    intercept_redirects: false

assetic:
    use_controller: true

doctrine:
    dbal:
        host: "%database_host_local%"
```

Here's my config_prod.yml:

```
imports:
    - { resource: config.yml }

doctrine:
    dbal:
        host: "%database_host_prod%"
```

(Rest of the database values are set in the config.yml, since I just want to change the host at the moment.)

Here's the parameters.yml(all values changed of course):

```
parameters:
    database_driver: pdo_mysql
    database_host_local: localhost
    database_host_prod: 11.11.11.11 # <-- This is never used if called in the config_prod.yml but IS used when called from the config_dev.yml
    database_port: 3306
    database_name: mydb
    database_user: user
    database_password: pass
    database_charset: utf8mb4
```

And finally here's the .htaccess -file that I use to change envs:

```
RedirectMatch permanent ^/app\.php/(.*) /$1

DirectoryIndex app.php

<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect to https-site:
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

    # Explicitly disable rewriting for front controllers
    RewriteRule app_dev.php - [L]
    RewriteRule app.php - [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    # Change below before deploying to production
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app_dev.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        # When mod_rewrite is not available, we instruct a temporary redirect of
        # the start page to the front controller explicitly so that the website
        # and the generated links can still be used.
        RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /app.php/
        # RedirectTemp cannot be used instead
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

I have not touched the AppKernel beyond adding bundles.

Why isn't the symfony using the config_prod.yml?

**Edit: app.php(First) and AppKernel.php(Second)**

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\ClassLoader\ApcClassLoader;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

$loader = require_once __DIR__.'/../app/bootstrap.php.cache';

// Enable APC for autoloading to improve performance.
// You should change the ApcClassLoader first argument to a unique prefix
// in order to prevent cache key conflicts with other applications
// also using APC.
/*
$apcLoader = new ApcClassLoader(sha1(__FILE__), $loader);
$loader->unregister();
$apcLoader->register(true);
*/

require_once __DIR__.'/../app/AppKernel.php';
//require_once __DIR__.'/../app/AppCache.php';

$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);
$kernel->loadClassCache();
//$kernel = new AppCache($kernel);

// When using the HttpCache, you need to call the method in your front controller instead of relying on the configuration parameter
//Request::enableHttpMethodParameterOverride();
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
Request::setTrustedProxies(array('127.0.0.1', $request->server->get('REMOTE_ADDR')));
$response = $kernel->handle($request);
$response->send();
$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

AppKernel.php:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\LoaderInterface;

class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
    public function registerBundles()
    {
        $bundles = array(
            new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\AsseticBundle(),
            new Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle(),
            new Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle(),
            new AppBundle\AppBundle(),
            new OldSound\RabbitMqBundle\OldSoundRabbitMqBundle(),
            new FOS\RestBundle\FOSRestBundle(),
            new FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserBundle(),
        );

        if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), array('dev', 'test'))) {
            $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\DebugBundle\DebugBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\SensioDistributionBundle();
        }

        return $bundles;
    }

    public function registerContainerConfiguration(LoaderInterface $loader)
    {
        $loader->load($this->getRootDir().'/config/config_'.$this->getEnvironment().'.yml');
    }

    public function __construct($environment, $debug)
    {
        date_default_timezone_set( 'Area/City' ); //<-- Changed the timezone from mine.
        parent::__construct($environment, $debug);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can we have the AppKernel.php and web/app.php class aswell ?

Comment: @MaximeK: There ya go.

Comment: Did you clear the cache? ;-)

Comment: Maybe in some case your webserver is not configured to show `app.php` and always point to `app_dev.php`.

Comment: @YetiCGN: Yes I cleared ALL the caches. :) For example I cleared the cache with this: php app/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug

Comment: @malcolm: Any further info on how this could have happened? What config could do this?

Comment: In other words: are you sure that you in production environment?

Comment: @malcolm: I just figured this one out. Thanks for contributing though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figured this one out. Simple thing really but easy to forget.
I'm using rabbitmq for messaging and I'm running rabbitmq consumers in the background. These consumers receive messages from the queues from time to time, BUT those messages never go through the app.php or app_dev.php, since the consumers are just processes running in the background! Silly me for not thinking this.

The consumers are started with a console command like this:

```
php app/console rabbitmq:etc..
```

And the docs state the following:

> By default, console commands run in the dev environment and you may
>   want to change this for some commands.

So the solution is to start the consumers like this:

```
php app/console --env=prod rabbitmq:etc..
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should try another way. So normally the `parameters.yml` is a local file which is generated from the `parameters.yml.dist` file. The `dist` file is a template where the composer updater create the values and write it to the `parameters.yml`. So it's better to exclude the `parameters.yml` from your repository. And change the values on that machine you need.

So for example if you are on your staging system then write your staging database to your parameters file. And if you are on you dev system then write your dev database to your configuration file. Then you don't need to specify a host for every environment and you can work with your file locally.

In my case i have another database for all unit tests. I overwrite them very easy when i overwrite the parameter like this. In `config_test.yml`

```
imports:
    - { resource: config_dev.yml }

parameters:
    database_name: "%database_name_unittest%"
```

That is working well. The last value is merged to your parameters and replaced.

Comment: One way to do it I suppose. What I worry is that the Symfony is not in prod-mode at all since it's not using the config_prod.yml. Is there a way to make sure that the system is indeed in prod mode and not dev?

Comment: When you set the second parameter to false then you have disabled the debug mode. Then you have the production mode. You can name the app.php own your own and set the environment.